# interaction between kml file map and java app

Tags: java, kml, markers

Can someone give me some ideas on how to do this:

In my java app(based in swing ui) I have to show a kml file this file contains a poligon with a delimited area and a  marker with the client's name, address, amount owed,  and other information.

I need that when the user makes a click in this marker and this show information
add a link to this information and when the user clicks on this link the info show in the marker popup get settet in the java JTextfields, somebody have ideas how to reach this, a folder with the kml file and the image that show my desired GUI [is here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz4RXIPrE7IFWHhQTFU4YTZBWTg&usp=sharing).

Thanks in advance for any answer

Answer (score 0):

The approach slightly depends on the library you are using to render your kml file. If using Geoxml3, you can update the function named "createInfoWindow" in the library. You can either pass the content from KML into this window or create an HTML string from the attributes and pass it to the function infoWindow.setContent("");